# how to enable intellisense in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: gulp, intellisense, visual-studio-code

I have been trying to get the IntelliSense activated inside VS Code.

When i do a `gulp.`, it is not giving me options like `task`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install gulp's typings file. I'm also not sure whether intellisense works without typescript for external modules.

```
npm i -g typings
typings init
typings install gulp --save-dev
```

Comment: so does Visual Studio Code provide inbuilt intellisense for Node.js?

Comment: With a typings file yes. typings install --ambient --save node

Comment: shell commands, yes. just run those in terminal/command line prompt.

Comment: i followed what you suggested and this is is how my typings.json file shaped up. But still no Intellisense.`{
  "name": "library",
  "version": false,
  "dependencies": {},
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "node": "registry:dt/node#4.0.0+20160330064709"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "registry:npm/gulp#3.8.0+20160211003958"
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

After installing typings and:

`typings install dt~gulp --global // --ambient deprecated use --global`

Then click on green light bulb in bottom-right corner of VSC, and add a jsconfig.json file

Check out:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/nodejs#_adding-a-jsconfigjson-configuration-file

You don't have to use

`///`

anymore... Also, you may need to close (using the "x") gulpfile.js, jsconfig.json, and package.json in the "Working Files" for jsconfig.json to recognize workspace.